# Laptop ACPI issues

Tags: boot, 17.10, laptop, acpi

I just installed Ubuntu 17.10 on my Asus n56vz laptop, and got a couple issues. The first one with display settings (I asked about it in another post). The second one with ACPI. There are many ACPI errors in log files, laptop doesn't reboot or shutdown, the laptop doesn't suspend when its lid is closed, etc.

Update: I was able to fix the reboot issue by editing the grub file:

```
sudo gedit /etc/default/grub
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash acpi=force"
sudo update-grub
```

Update: The above solution worked well for a few reboots only.

Update: Please find below a list of ACPI log messages

```
ACPI Error: Method parse/execution failed \_SB.PCI0.PEG0.PEGP._DSM, AE_AML_PACKAGE_LIMIT (20170531/psparse-550)
ACPI Error: Method parse/execution failed \_SB.PCI0.GFX0._DSM, AE_AML_PACKAGE_LIMIT (20170531/psparse-550)
ACPI Exception: AE_AML_PACKAGE_LIMIT, Index (0x000000003) is beyond end of object (length 0x0) (20170531/exoparg2-427)
ACPI Error: Method parse/execution failed \_SB.PCI0.GFX0._DSM, AE_AML_PACKAGE_LIMIT (20170531/psparse-550)
ACPI Exception: AE_AML_PACKAGE_LIMIT, Index (0x000000003) is beyond end of object (length 0x0) (20170531/exoparg2-427)
ACPI Error: Method parse/execution failed \_PR.CPU0._PDC, AE_AML_OPERAND_TYPE (20170531/psparse-550)
ACPI Exception: AE_AML_OPERAND_TYPE, While resolving operands for [OpcodeName unavailable] (20170531/dswexec-461)
ACPI Error: Needed type [Reference], found [Integer] ffff9ff0dc58c2d0 (20170531/exresop-103)
```

Comment: "there are many ACPI errors in log files"  so we are going to need to guess what these are? Please add them to the question otherwise we have absolutely nothing to go on

Answer (score 0):

Most of these ACPI issues were resolved by switching from Nouveau display driver to the Nvidia 384.111 driver. Now I can reboot and shutdown my laptop without any problems, though I still have a few ACPI errors.

```
ACPI Error: Method parse/execution failed \_PR.CPU0._PDC, AE_AML_OPERAND_TYPE (20170531/psparse-550)
ACPI Exception: AE_AML_OPERAND_TYPE, While resolving operands for [OpcodeName unavailable] (20170531/dswexec-461)
ACPI Error: Needed type [Reference], found [Integer] ffff942bdc58c870 (20170531/exresop-103)
```